# WORDPRESS: Where do I delete my site?

Tags: wordpress

I've looked absolutely everywhere for an answer to this, and so far have not gotten any that have solved my problem. It seems like it should be simple, but Im either getting answers that tell me to press a "Delete Account" button in my dashboard that simply IS NOT there, or someone says "look it up on Google" or something else that is not at all helpful. I've looked and am getting very frustrated. So, here's my question(s):

1. If I cancel the hosting (Blue Host), will it automatically cancel all payments relating to the site? That is, is signing up on WordPress free, with the hosting being the part that is paid? I can't find statements or anything related to the WordPress part of it, so I'm hoping that the hosting is the only part I'm paying for (this site was started a few years ago, and I just don't have time for it, so I don't remember anymore.)
2. Can a Wordpress.org account/site actually be deleted? I've emptied all the contents as stated in the documentation, but when it comes to actually pressing "Delete Account," the button is no where to be found in my dashboard! As long as I'm not paying for it to just sit there, I guess I can leave it, but I'd prefer to delete it altogether, if possible.

Thank you to anyone who offers constructive advice on this topic. I know others have asked about this, but none of those solutions have worked, so I'm asking again. (It also doesn't help that WordPress doesn't offer direct support, only forums, so if you happen to know of a good resource outside of their own documentation--which, as stated, hasn't helped me--I'll appreciate the referral.)

Answer (score 0):

if you want to delete your site just delete all the file for this site in public_html folder. or if you want delete hosting for this site contact with your hosting provider. you can do it if you want to do.
But I think you can sell your domain, if your domain age is above 5 years may be your domain has SEO domain authority (DA) . you can sell it .